# simple problem in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

If $\{f_n\},f \in L^p(\Omega)$, and for any $V\subset\subset \Omega$, $lim_{n->\infty}\int_V f_n d\Omega = \int_V fd\Omega$, is it true that $lim_{n->\infty}\int_{\Omega}f_n d\Omega = \int_\Omega fd\Omega$

Comment: What does "$\subset\subset$" mean?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Ecxhange!  Could you include your attempts on this problem?

Comment: @David: standard notation, $V$ has compact closure contained in $\Omega$.  You could also ask  what are $\Omega$ and $d\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. Take $\Omega = (0,1)$ and
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n & x \le 1/n, \\ 0 & \text{else}.\end{cases}$$
Then, forall compact subsets $[a,b]$ of $(0,1)$, you have
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f_n \, \mathrm{d}x = 0 = \int_a^b 0 \, \mathrm{d}x,$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n \, \mathrm{d}x = 1 \ne 0= \int_0^1 0 \, \mathrm{d}x.$

You need some additional assumptions, e.g., the boundedness of $f_n$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ for some $p > 1$.